# LINQ ordering with multiple joins

Tags: c#, linq, join

Basic schema that I have inherited (no foreign keys):

```
Tasks (TaskID, Description, ElementID, UserID)
Elements (ElementID, Description)
Users (UserID, FirstName, LastName)
```

I need to order a `List<Task>`, first by `Element.Description`, then by `User.FirstName`, then by `User.LastName`

I've managed so far to order by `Element.Description` using the following:

```
List<Task> tasks = db.Tasks.ToList();
List<Element> elements = db.Elements.ToList();
List<User> users = db.Users.ToList();    

tasks = tasks.Join(elements,
    t => t.ElementID,
    e => e.ElementID,
    (t, e) => new { t, e })
    .OrderBy(m => m.e.Description)
    .Select(m => m.t).ToList();
```

How do I join/order with more than one other entity? (ie. I need to add `users` to the above query and order by its fields)

(I know query syntax might be more suitable for joins but I've become more familiar/comfortable with lambda syntax, so it would be preferred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to `Join` the result of your first `Join` with the list of `User`, then use [`ThenBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.95).aspx) to order by the `User` fields :

```
tasks = tasks
    .Join(elements,
        t => t.ElementID,
        e => e.ElementID,
        (t, e) => new { t, e })
    .Join(users,
        x => x.t.UserID,
        u => u.UserID,
        (x, u) => new { x.t, x.e, u })
    .OrderBy(m => m.e.Description)
    .ThenBy(m => m.u.FirstName)
    .ThenBy(m => m.u.LastName)
    .Select(m => m.t)
    .ToList();
```